# time.sleep() function not working

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I'm using time.sleep() in a program but the lines seem to be running out of order. Here is the code:

```
print("Line 1")
time.sleep(1)
print("Line 2")
time.sleep(1)
print("Line 3")
time.sleep(1)
```

And it runs like this:

(waits)
Line 1
Line 2
(waits)
Line 3

Instead of:

Line 1 (waits) Line 2 (waits) Line 3 (waits)

I've had this problem with a lot of programs that I use this function for, never really found a fix. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Try running without output buffering, i.e. `python -u foo.py`. You can also try to call `sys.stdout.flush()` after every `print`, just to test it.

Comment: In Python3 you could flush the buffers in a simple way: `print(line1, flush=True)`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new at python. Could you explain in simpler terms?

Comment: When you print, it may not actually print directly to the terminal window, but rather gather up a few bytes (or even a few lines) worth in a buffer before "flushing" this buffer to the terminal window. This is to make printing faster. If you turn off buffering, all printing goes directly to the terminal window at once.